# Do you think Meta Stack Overflow is necessary for Stack Overflow now?

Tags: discussion, meta

I understand the objective of Meta Stack Overflow is `Support, feature requests, or bug reports for the core Stack Exchange engine that powers all Stack Exchange websites`. So many people participate here and questions that required for Stack Overflow is nearly completed (personal opinion) because I asked some questions and it already existed. (This is 90% of my questions). Do you think Meta Stack Overflow is necessary for Stack Overflow now?

Comment: As long as the site gets one new question per day, it's needed...

Comment: Meta works as Maintenance of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Absolutely, yes.

First of all, Meta Stack Overflow right now also functions as the meta site for the entire Stack Exchange network. But leaving that aside...

There are Stack Overflow-specific questions coming up every day that haven't yet been covered. Tag merge requests, discussions or calls to action on specific issues, bug reports for new features (we are certainly not done developing!), and suggestions for new stuff. Sure, some of it gets repeated, but it's not necessarily a bad thing.

Other times, we (the employees) have announcements that we want to bring to everyone's attention but that aren't quite big enough for the [blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com), or ideas of our own that we want to run by the community here. Meta is a big part of what makes Stack Exchange sites work, so it's definitely still needed.